# Pytorch, custom layer works in Sequential but not in Functional

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using convGRU from [here](https://github.com/happyjin/ConvGRU-pytorch) and it works OK when I use it in the Sequential mode but it does not with the Functional. When I say it does not work, I mean that I'm getting black predictions from the Functional, while from the Sequential the outputs are similar to the inputs. Everything else in the code remains the same.
Below is an example of what I consistently get with one and another (being the first row the target and the second the prediction)

[image]

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()
        self.rnn1 = ConvGRU(
            input_size=(64, 64),
            input_dim=1,
            hidden_dim=1,
            kernel_size=(3, 3),
            num_layers=1,
            dtype=dtype,
            batch_first=True,
            bias=True,
            return_all_layers=False,
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.rnn1(x)
        return x
```

versus

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    ConvGRU(
        input_size=(64, 64),
        input_dim=1,
        hidden_dim=1,
        kernel_size=(3, 3),
        num_layers=1,
        dtype=dtype,
        batch_first=True,
        bias=True,
        return_all_layers=False,
    )
)
```

Any idea if when programming custom layers there should be different considerations for when it is intended to use in Functional or Sequential?

Thanks!

Comment: Both should be equivalent provided the rest of the code is the same and `ConvGRU` is the same in both cases. It looks like in the first case you are not providing data with `batch` as first dimension as you should while do so properly in the second ("non-functional") case, would check that out. BTW. neither is functional approach, `functional` can be found in `torch.nn.functional` and definitely shouldn't be overused (usually used for activations or pooling).